# Get GPS coordinates of moving marker on Google Maps iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I need to pick coordinates of current marker position on Google maps. It should update coordinates as marker is moving on map.

I'm using **GoogleMaps** , **GooglePlaces** and **GooglePlacePicker** API's. I can get nearby places using **GooglePlacePicker** API but I want to pick exact coordinates of location where marker is present.

It is already done in **Uber**?

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {

    GMSMapView *mapView_;
    GMSMarker *marker_;

    float currentLatitude;
    float currentLongitude;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic)CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [_locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [_locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [_locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        if ([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
            [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        }
    }
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    NSLog(@"%@",locations);
    CLLocation *currentLoc=[locations objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"CurrentLoc : %@",currentLoc);
    _coordinate=currentLoc.coordinate;
    currentLatitude = currentLoc.coordinate.latitude;
    currentLongitude = currentLoc.coordinate.longitude;
}


-(void)plotMarkerForLatitude:(float)latitude andLongitude:(float)longitude {

    // Now create maker on current location
    if (marker_ == NULL) {
        marker_ = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D target =
    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

    marker_.position = target;
    marker_.title = @"title";

    marker_.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
    NSLog(@"%f %f",latitude,longitude);
    marker_.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker"];
    marker_.snippet = @"Address";
    marker_.map = mapView_;
}
```

In Plist :

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow access to get your current location</string>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Suppose I'm sitting in Mumbai and I move marker to New York as We move in GooglePlacePicker. Shall I get coordinates of New York ?

Comment: Do you got the result?

Comment: I think it is used to update device current location. This is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

This can possibly be done by implementing the [GMSMapViewDelegate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p) protocol. See the [guide to events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/events) and the list of methods on the `GMSMapViewDelegate`.

As mentioned in the documentation,

> Applications can use this event to trigger a refresh of markers or other content being displayed on the GMSMapView, rather than, for example, reloading the content on every camera change.

You may also check [Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/) for more information on what other APIs you can use along with Maps iOS SDK to build location-relevant apps and sites.